# twitter4j no authentication challenges found

Tags: java, android, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

Been trying to use twitter4j to post a tweet for couple days now without luck, what i want to do is for a person to post their new top score on their timeline from the app at the end of a round. Here is my code

```
          @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tweetr);
    Button tweetr = (Button)findViewById(R.id.tweetr);

    //create a new twitter configuration using user details
    tweetTwitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
    tweetTwitter.setOAuthConsumer(TWIT_KEY, TWIT_SECRET);


        //create a twitter instance
   // tweetTwitter = new TwitterFactory(twitConf).getInstance();



    tweetr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


          dt.execute();

        }
    });



}


public class TweetTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object... values) {
        /* try {
            //requestToken = tweetTwitter.getOAuthRequestToken(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL);
        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(requestToken.getAuthenticationURL())));
        */
        try {
            requestToken = tweetTwitter.getOAuthRequestToken(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL);
            String authUrl = requestToken.getAuthenticationURL();
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(authUrl)));
        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


      return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Log.d("URI", "DONE");
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }




}



@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    final Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
    if(uri != null ){

                Log.d("URI", uri.toString());

                Thread th = new Thread(){
                    public void run(){
                        try {
                            String verifier = uri.getQueryParameter("oauth_verifier");
                            String oauthToken = uri.getQueryParameter("oauth_token");

                            RequestToken reqToken = tweetTwitter.getOAuthRequestToken(oauthToken,verifier); 


                            AccessToken accessToken = tweetTwitter.getOAuthAccessToken(reqToken);
                            String token = accessToken.getToken(), secret = accessToken.getTokenSecret();

                        } catch (TwitterException ex) {
                            Log.e("Main.onNewIntent", "" + ex.getMessage());
                        }


                    }};
                    th.start();
      }else
        Log.d("URI", "FAILED");         


    }
```

}

This is my error print out

```
10-23 15:35:18.661: D/TWIT ER(2392): No authentication challenges foundRelevant discussions can be found on the Internet at:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

refer to the [javadoc](http://twitter4j.org/en/javadoc/twitter4j/TwitterBaseImpl.html) of Twitter4J

```
In order to get access acquire AccessToken using xAuth, you must apply by sending an email to api@twitter.com â€” all other applications will receive an HTTP 401 error.
```

Comment: ohhh, but is there still a way to do this without using xAuth