# To Get Twitter followers list

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j

I am developing an Android app to get Twitter followers.The following code is  used for authentication and I have logged in successfully.

```
consumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(
                        key,
                        secret);
                CommonsHttpOAuthProvider provider = new CommonsHttpOAuthProvider(
                        "http://twitter.com/oauth/request_token",
                        "http://twitter.com/oauth/access_token",
                        "http://twitter.com/oauth/authorize");

                String authUrl = provider.retrieveRequestToken(consumer,
                        TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL);
                Log.e("Twittwer ", "Please authorize this app!");

                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                        Uri.parse(authUrl)));
```

In order to get the list of followers I have used the code below but I got error and the logcat is attached

```
AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken(consumer.getToken(),
                    consumer.getTokenSecret());
            ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(key);
            builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(secret);
            Configuration conf = builder.build();
            twitter = new TwitterFactory(conf).getInstance();
            twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(accessToken);
            IDs followersId = twitter.getFollowersIDs(twitter.getId());
            do {
                for (long i : followersId.getIDs()) {



                    System.out.println("follower ID #" + i);
                    System.out.println(twitter.showUser(i).getName());
                    System.out.println(twitter.showUser(i)
                            .getProfileImageURL());
                    System.out.println(twitter.showUser(i).getURL());

                }
            } while (followersId.hasNext());
        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            System.out.println("e........"+e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
```

logcat:

```
02-18 16:13:10.632: W/System.err(734): Received authentication challenge is null 02-18 16:13:10.682: W/System.err(734): Relevant discussions can be found on the Internet at: 02-18 16:13:10.682: W/System.err(734):    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=a1259409 or 02-18 16:13:10.702: W/System.err(734):     http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=06b97274 02-18 16:13:10.712: W/System.err(734): TwitterException{exceptionCode=[a1259409-06b97274 2e9324ac-d074d7d2], statusCode=-1, message=null, code=-1, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, version=3.0.3} 02-18 16:13:10.752: W/System.err(734):     at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:192) 02-18 16:13:10.903: W/System.err(734):   at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.request(HttpClientWrapper.java:61) 02-18 16:13:11.012: W/System.err(734):  at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.get(HttpClientWrapper.java:89) 02-18 16:13:11.062: W/System.err(734):  at twitter4j.TwitterBaseImpl.fillInIDAndScreenName(TwitterBaseImpl.java:126) 02-18 16:13:11.123: W/System.err(734):     at twitter4j.TwitterBaseImpl.getId(TwitterBaseImpl.java:118) 02-18 16:13:11.142: W/System.err(734):     at com.nest.twitterfriendsfinder.MainActivity$getFollowers.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:276) 02-18 16:13:11.152: W/System.err(734):     at com.nest.twitterfriendsfinder.MainActivity$getFollowers.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1) 02-18 16:13:11.192: W/System.err(734):   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264) 02-18 16:13:11.212: W/System.err(734):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305) 02-18 16:13:11.232: W/System.err(734):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137) 02-18 16:13:11.302: W/System.err(734):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208) 02-18 16:13:11.362: W/System.err(734):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076) 02-18 16:13:11.362: W/System.err(734):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569) 02-18 16:13:11.362: W/System.err(734):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856) 02-18 16:13:11.362: W/System.err(734): Caused by: java.io.IOException: Received authentication challenge is null 02-18 16:13:11.372: W/System.err(734):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.processAuthHeader(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:397) 02-18 16:13:11.372: W/System.err(734):  at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.processResponseHeaders(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345) 02-18 16:13:11.372: W/System.err(734):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:276) 02-18 16:13:11.372: W/System.err(734):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:479) 02-18 16:13:11.372: W/System.err(734):    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpResponseImpl.<init>(HttpResponseImpl.java:34) 02-18 16:13:11.382: W/System.err(734):     at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:156)
```

What is the issue in this code.I read in some post that to check the Timestamp in emulator.But time and date in emulator is correct.Please provide me some help.Thanks in advance..

[EDIT]
I  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13042325/1767260) right?

Comment: Please help me...Not found any solution.I am stuck in this issue

Answer (score 0):

In my project I have this code in order to fetch the followers.
Maybe the main point is related to using an `AsyncTask`.

```
    if (twitter == null){
        ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        Configuration conf = builder
        .setOAuthConsumerKey(CONSUMER_KEY)
        .setOAuthConsumerSecret(CONSUMER_SECRET)
        .setOAuthAccessToken(oAuthAccessToken)
        .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(oAuthAccessTokenSecret)
        .build();
        twitter = new TwitterFactory(conf).getInstance();
    }


    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            long lCursor = -1;
            AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken(oAuthAccessToken, oAuthAccessTokenSecret);
            long userId = accessToken.getUserId();
            try {
                IDs followersIDs = twitter.getFollowersIDs(userId, lCursor);
                do {
                    for (long i : friendsIDs.getIDs()){
                        Log.d("follower ID #", String.valueOf(i));
                    }
                }while(followersIDs.hasNext());
            } catch (TwitterException e) {
                Log.i("fetchFollowers", e.getErrorMessage());
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void param) {
        }

    }.execute();
```