# No authentication challenges found

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

I tried to use

```
try {
  new TwitterFactory(new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_KEY)
                .setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_SECRET)
                .setOAuthAccessToken(TWITTER_TOKEN)
                .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(TWITTER_TOKEN_SECRET)
                .build()).getInstance().updateStatus("HELLO WORLD!");
} catch (TwitterException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But as soon as I run it, it gives me this error: [image]

this might be a possible answer: `In order to get access acquire AccessToken using xAuth, you must apply by sending an email to api@twitter.com â€” all other applications will receive an HTTP 401 error.` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13041146/twitter4j-no-authentication-challenges-found) but his answer is not complete (does not have steps to follow)

How to fix this? Thanks!